# In an aeroplane's jet engine, where is the forward force applied to the mass of the plane?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, aircraft

In a standard jet engine on a standard aeroplane, is the majority of forward force received by the aeroplane (which causes it to be propelled forwards) applied on the compressor blades, the rotor blades, the internal body of the blade surrounds, a combination of these, or somewhere else?

Comment: It seems as an engineering question to me. As far as physics goes, [Tsiolkovsky equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) describes jet engine - the particular implementations being a matter of engineering. However, it could be a viable question, if you supply it with appropriate image and/or the explanation of the terms involved.

Comment: Interesting answer over on aviation -> https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/46349/3159

Answer (score 1):

the thrust force is taken up by the bearings that support the compressor section. These bearings are coupled to the engine casing by struts, and the engine casing is then attached to the structure of the plane. IN this way the engine thrust is conveyed to the aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

The two rotor blades at front intake stream and back outwards stream produce a constant stream of air though the burning chamber.

In the burning chamber the temperatur is lifted from 200 K to 800 K, increasing the product $p V =n R T$ in the law of ideal gas  by a factor of 4, the burnt fuel adds H_2O and CO_2 a factor of 2 to particle number $n$.

It follows that by irrelevance of the athmospheric pressure the output stream has approximately 8 times of the momentum of the input stream. The propulsion force is the change of meomentum as in a rocket. The difference only is that the oxygen is coming in from the atmosphere.

Part of the energy and momentum is transfered back to the intake compressor. The small intake turbine with many blades and the big outlet turbine on the same axis act as a torque converter from high momentum to high angular velocity in terms of blade numbers per rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a lot on the flight Mach number.

You are right, since the compressor blades create a pressure difference, this will become thrust when multiplied with their projected area. But there are other sections inside an engine where pressure is acting on a rear-facing area: The [diffuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuser_(thermodynamics)) where speed is converted into pressure by a widening of the cross section.

[image: longitudinal cross section of a jet engine]

Longitudinal cross section of a generic jet engine ([source](http://cast-safety.org/pdf/3_engine_fundamentals.pdf))

At low Mach numbers, there is not much speed to convert. However, once we look at supersonic engines, this can become the dominant source of thrust. For example, at Mach 3.2 the intake would contribute 54% of all thrust of the J-58 engines of the [SR-71 spy plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird). Similar numbers can be found for the XB-70. The pressure rise from carefully cascaded shocks in front of the engine and up to the throat (the point of the smallest cross section) of the intake raises air pressure by a factor of almost 40 at Mach 3.2 (and density by a factor of 13.5). This pressure acts on the rear-facing areas past the throat such that it pushes the airplane forward.

[image: Thrust distribution over Mach]

Thrust distribution over Mach ([source](https://www.enginehistory.org/Convention/2014/SR-71Inlts/SR-71Inlts.shtml))

Of course, the same pressure would also act on the compressor if it would not work hard to keep the air flowing by swallowing what is flowing into the intake. At Mach 3 the turbomachinery will only produce a relatively small pressure rise in order to keep the air temperature in the combustion chamber low enough such that the energy released by combustion will heat the air further instead of [dissociating an already hot gas](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/using-pure-o2-for-jet-engine-combustion/10074#10074) and melting the turbine further downstream.

Comment: "pressure is acting on a forward-facing area" I presume you mean acting on a rear-facing area?

Comment: @Claud I guess you are right. Corrected.